# matplotlib show minutes time-series in hour (change xticklabels)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, timeserieschart

My code which show if product is stockout in every minutes in a day:

```
sq_t = df_stock_quantity_log[['is_stockout']].resample('T').ffill().fillna(0).astype(int).squeeze()

nrows =10

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, figsize=(18, 40))

for idx, date in enumerate(df.index[:nrows]):
    s = sq_t[date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]
    if len(s) < 24*60:
        s = np.concatenate((np.zeros(24*60-len(s)),s))
    axs[idx].plot(s, label=idx)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The output is

[image]

I want to change xtick to 0 ~ 23 and alter code to

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, figsize=(18, 40))


for idx, date in enumerate(df.index[:nrows]):
    s = sq_t[date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]

    if len(s) < 24*60:
        s = np.concatenate((np.zeros(24*60-len(s)),s))
    axs[idx].plot(s, label=idx)
    axs[idx].set_xticks(s)
    axs[idx].set_xticklabels(['h %d' % (ii/ 60,) for ii in range(0, 24*60 , 60)])

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

But the result is very bad:

[image]

---

`sq_t` information:

[image]

[image]

PS: I know the xticklabel of first day pic is wrong, because I don't set proper datetime index to it. It just for example here .

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the result looked bad in question. 
My solution is drop the DatetimeIndex of `sq_t` at first, then set_xticks would look good.

```
sq_t = df_stock_quantity_log[['is_stockout']].resample('T').ffill().fillna(0).astype(int).squeeze()

nrows =10

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, figsize=(18, 40))


for idx, date in enumerate(df.index[:nrows]):
    s = sq_t[date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]

    if len(s) < 24*60:
        s = pd.Series(np.concatenate((np.zeros(24*60-len(s)),s)))
    axs[idx].plot(s.reset_index(drop=True), label=idx)
    axs[idx].set_xticks(range(0, 24*60, 60))
    axs[idx].set_xticklabels(['h%d' % (ii/ 60,) for ii in range(0, 24*60 , 60)])

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]